# Page works when linked too, but breaks on reload

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to add VueTyper to my Nuxt site and when you follow the link to my about page it works on the initial load, but if you reload the page it breaks.

```
<template>
    <vue-typer text="Why does this break"></vue-typer>
</template>

<script>
import { VueTyper } from 'vue-typer'


  export default {
   components:{
       VueTyper
   }
  }

</script>
```

I recieve 
"ReferenceError
document is not defined" on reload.

Comment: it seems `vue-typer` doesn't support SSR, so pop up this error.

Comment: As @Sphinx suggested, it doesn't support SSR or you are messing up with Routes.

Answer (score 0):

VueTyper doesn't support SSR. There several workaround for this.

1) You can run nuxt in spa mode https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-mode/

2) You can use no-ssr tag https://nuxtjs.org/api/components-no-ssr/

3) You can add vueTyper as a plugin with ssr: false https://github.com/cngu/vue-typer/issues/1#issuecomment-368987826

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  plugins: [
    ...
    { src: 'plugins/vue-typer.js', ssr: false}
  ],
  ...
}
```

Maybe 2 and 3 should be used together, didn't tested myself.